# fatal: Could not read from remote repository.; because of static machine login

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

I cannot push to my git repo on bitbucket. My url is set correctly, I have the ssh key in the account, and the permissions are fine.

I have the following output when I run `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.com`:

```
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
logged in as servandoavila1.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to bitbucket.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3508, received 1836 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 22807.7, received 11937.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Then

```
cchilders@cchilders-Latitude-E7240:~/projects/foodtruck-remake$ git push
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It seems I'm still logged in as my friend on the machine, `servandoavila1`. But I recently fixed the global `user.email`/`user.name` of git. How can I push to this repo?

Comment: See the error. You cannot ssh to bitbucket. Yuo can use git though. What is the error when you try `git push ...`?

Comment: good point, ty  ,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you've posted here from `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.com` (nit: use .org) suggests you're authenticating as your friend. The git committer name and email are for git's internal tracking mechanisms, not for authenticating to remote systems, so you're still trying to push as your friend - and it looks like s/he doesn't have access to that repo.

You have a couple options here:

1. Give your friend write access to that repo
2. Set up a separate SSH keypair on that system; associate it with your Bitbucket user; and update your git remotes to use your username instead of your friend's or "git" (e.g. `git remote set-url origin username@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git`)
3. Use HTTPS (e.g. `git remote set-url origin https://username@bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git`)

Comment: wow you're awesome Mr. Redmond, and #2 was what I tried first, it worked. Thank you